# Null pointer exception while reading an excel file in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am new to Java and I am trying to read an excel file. 
   jars included: `log4j-1.2.17`,`poi-3.9`,`poi-ooxml-3.5-beta5`,`poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029`,`poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-beta1`,`xmlbeans-2.5.0`,`xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.4.0`

```
package net.codejava.excel;

import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class SPACE_CreateThroughExcel{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        SPACE_CreateThroughExcel create = new SPACE_CreateThroughExcel();
        create.read();
    }
    public void read(){

        try {           
            String excelFilePath = "C:/Users/Rachana/workspace/SPACEOM/WebContent/Data/Data.xlsx";
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
            XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(is);
            XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
            System.out.println(rowNum);
            int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

        String[][] data = new String[rowNum][colNum];
        for(int i=0; i< rowNum; i++){
            XSSFRow row  = ws.getRow(i);
                for(int j=0;j<colNum;j++){
                    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                    String value = cellToString(cell);
                    data[i][j] = value;
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
        }

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static String cellToString(XSSFCell cell){
        int type;
        Object result;
        type = cell.getCellType();

        switch(type){
            case 0:
                result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                break;
            case 1:
                result = cell.getStringCellValue();
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("No support");

        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

This is my code. I am trying to read the cells of excel file into a 2D array which I want to later use in my jsp file. When I run it it shows the following errors:

```
at net.codejava.excel.SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.cellToString(SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.java:46)
at net.codejava.excel.SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.read(SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.java:30)
at net.codejava.excel.SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.main(SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.java:64)
```

My excel file is something like this:

```
 SPLD_DeviceID_Mfg  SPLD_DeviceID_ModelNo   SPLD_DeviceID_SrNo                                                                              
                                                    4  
                                  apl               3
```

Some of the fields in my excel file are empty. I need to store the empty value in my array for later use. I am checking only the types for integer and String. What to do in case of null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: is there any condition for null value in cell

Comment: List complete stacktrace.

Comment: I have listed the complete stacktrace.  java.lang.NullPointerException
 at net.codejava.excel.SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.cellToString(SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.java:46)
 at net.codejava.excel.SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.read(SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.java:31)
 at net.codejava.excel.SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.main(SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.java:63)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the sheet you are fetching doesn't exist. So probably the error is in this line : `XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("SPACE_License");`. Do verify it. `ws` is coming out as `null`.

Comment: after correcting it at net.codejava.excel.SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.cellToString(SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.java:46)
 at net.codejava.excel.SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.read(SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.java:30)
 at net.codejava.excel.SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.main(SPACE_CreateThroughExcel.java:64) still remains

Comment: please post it as a seperate question, it would be too messy to discuss it here, or just edit this question only.

Comment: @Rachana You should take a careful look at the code, teh cell you are passing on to cellToString method is null. I would suggest you to go through java doc of the functions you are using. You should be having a check if cell is null.

Answer (score -2):

Some times will get `NUllPointerException` error while reading data from excel when we didn't pass a fis object parameter to `WorkbookFactory` or `XSSFWorkbook` class object.

It should be: `WorkbookFactory.create(fis)` or `XSSFWorkbook(fis)`